# Interesting issue with fonts in PyGame

Tags: fonts, pygame

Working with texts in PyGame is a very interesting pastime...

I presume that we all know how to handle text from rendering to blitting, so I skip the code snippet here and dive right "in medias res": I wanted to use Lucida Calligraphy - impossible! I tried a number of totally random other fonts (e.g. standards like Times New Roman and Arial, but also rarer fonts like Monotype Corsiva and the like, even a self.made one) and the program perfectly works. Changing the font to Lucida Calligraphy makes PyGame load for hours - to no avail.

Can anybody with some knowledge on fonts shed some light on this issue? I find it very interesting, but I can't happen to find an answer to it...

Thank you :)
Patric

Comment: Have you included the font file?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely installed on the machine I tested (I have it in word and font.get_fonts() also lists it)
Dominic Kexel's answer down here answers my question. With the italic flag it really works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Lucida Calligraphy` is an italic-only font; so when you load it, set the `italic` flag:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Lucida Calligraphy', 20, italic=True)
```

[image]

Also true for other italic only fonts, like `Lucida Handwriting` or `Brush Script`.

[I filed a bug report](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/197/).